# How could I configure the reward for a substrate Aura validator?

Tags: substrate, polkadot

Now that the PoA is running with multiple Aura validators in my substrate-node-template.  How could I configure that reward amount or value for my Aura validators?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I got it working, PoA will reward the validator who created the block using the tip as the sample value for the fees, here are the steps:

1. Install the pallet_authorship

```
pallet-authorship = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.23" }
```

2. Configure the pallet to get the current author of the block

```
pub struct AuraAccountAdapter;
impl frame_support::traits::FindAuthor<AccountId> for AuraAccountAdapter {
    fn find_author<'a, I>(digests: I) -> Option<AccountId>
        where I: 'a + IntoIterator<Item=(frame_support::ConsensusEngineId, &'a [u8])>
    {
        pallet_aura::AuraAuthorId::<Runtime>::find_author(digests).and_then(|k| {
            AccountId::try_from(k.as_ref()).ok()
        })
    }
}
impl pallet_authorship::Config for Runtime {
    type FindAuthor = AuraAccountAdapter;
    type UncleGenerations = ();
    type FilterUncle = ();
    type EventHandler =  ();
}
```

3. Create OnUnbalanced implementation of Author and DealWithFees

```
use crate::{Authorship, Balances};
use frame_support::traits::{Imbalance, OnUnbalanced};
use crate::sp_api_hidden_includes_construct_runtime::hidden_include::traits::Currency;
use crate::AccountId;

type NegativeImbalance = <Balances as Currency<AccountId>>::NegativeImbalance;

pub struct Author;
impl OnUnbalanced<NegativeImbalance> for Author {
    fn on_nonzero_unbalanced(amount: NegativeImbalance) {
        if let Some(author) = Authorship::author() {
            Balances::resolve_creating(&author, amount);
        }
    }
}

pub struct DealWithFees;
impl OnUnbalanced<NegativeImbalance> for DealWithFees {
    fn on_unbalanceds<B>(mut fees_then_tips: impl Iterator<Item = NegativeImbalance>) {
        if let Some(fees) = fees_then_tips.next() {
            let mut split = fees.ration(80, 20);
            if let Some(tips) = fees_then_tips.next() {
                // for tips, if any, 80% to treasury, 20% to block author (though this can be anything)
                tips.ration_merge_into(80, 20, &mut split);
            }
            //Treasury::on_unbalanced(split.0);
            Author::on_unbalanced(split.1);
        }
    }
}
```

4. Call the implementation in the pallet_transaction_payment tuple OnChargeTransaction

```
impl pallet_transaction_payment::Config for Runtime {
    type OnChargeTransaction = CurrencyAdapter<Balances, crate::impls::DealWithFees>;
    type OperationalFeeMultiplier = ConstU8<5>;
    type WeightToFee = IdentityFee<Balance>;
    type LengthToFee = IdentityFee<Balance>;
    type FeeMultiplierUpdate = ();
}
```

Also added in my blog: https://hgminerva.wordpress.com/2022/06/21/how-to-pay-the-block-author-validator-on-a-proof-of-authority-poa-consensus-in-substrate/